# Problemas para usar list_display en django

Tags: python, django

Estoy revisando tutoriales y no me aparece la forma para personalizar la tabla de mi administrador. Es decir se ve como esto, osea yo quiero que la tabla sea más descriptiva pero sólo me coloca "clientes", no aparece ni el ID ni la licencia, zip, etc.:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les presento el código, en serio no le veo ningún error pero bueno, soy novata. Gracias!!!! :) :

> Models

```
class Clientes(models.Model):
    nombre =models.CharField(max_length=80)
    apellido=models.CharField(max_length=80)
    licencia = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    zip = models.IntegerField()
    ciudad = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    telefono = models.IntegerField()
    fax = models.IntegerField()
    descuento = models.IntegerField()
    correo = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    carro = models.ForeignKey(Carro,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}: {self.nombre} {self.apellido} {self.licencia} {self.direccion}'
```

> Admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from clientes.models import Clientes, Carro, ClienteEmpresa
# Register your models here.

class ClientesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display= ('nombre', 'apellido', 'licencia')


admin.site.register(Clientes)
```

Comment: y cual es el problema que tienes?

Comment: hola!!! acabo de hacer una mayor descripción y agregué una imagen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para registrar un modelo en el admin tienes varias alternativas:

1. Registrar el modelo con la interfaz por defecto

```py
admin.site.register(Clientes)
```

que es igual a...

```py
class ClientesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Clientes, ClientesAdmin)
```

2. Registrar el modelo con una interfaz customizable

```py
class ClientesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display= ('nombre', 'apellido', 'licencia')

admin.site.register(Clientes, ClientesAdmin)
```

En tu código estas usando la opción **1)**, es decir que estas utilizando la interfaz por defecto. Para corregir el comportamiento debes pasar como segundo parámetro a `ClientesAdmin` en el método `admin.site.register`.

**Nota.** Puedes utilizar el decorador `admin.register` para ahorrarte `admin.site.register(...)`. En este caso tu código quedaría como:

```py
...

@admin.register(Clientes)
class ClientesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display= ('nombre', 'apellido', 'licencia')
```

Comment: Me salvaste la vida!!!